# How do I adjust Steam chat font sizes?

Tags: steam

It seems that [a recent Steam update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/10548/) increased font size in chat to 'improve readability'. Unfortunately, this only changed the font size in the in the conversation area and nowhere else in the chat window, making the interface jarring to use. How can I change it back to the way it was before?

---

As of May, 6, another Steam update changed the chat input font to about 16 points [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyzyr.png), and there doesn't seem to be a corresponding styles setting to adjust its font size. Is there a way to adjust the friends chat input font size?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[You can edit the Steam UI's style files](http://www.overclock.net/t/999232/a-quick-guide-on-how-to-increase-font-size-in-steam-chats) to change font sizes. The files `steam.styles` and `gameoverlay.styles` control the look-and-feel of the Steam UI and the overlay UI, respectively. You can locate these by navigating to your Steam folder (usually under `Program Files`) and navigating into the `resource` then `styles` folders.

By finding the lines that contain `font-size=`, you can change the font size of any UI element.

Specifically, to change the chat font size, find the code blocks that look like this:

```
friends_chat_text
{
textcolor="text"
selectedtextcolor="TextentrySelected"
SelectedBgColor="focus"
font-size=20
}
```

And change the `font-size` to 14 or whatever is comfortable. There are multiple UI types used in Steam Chat, so you will want to inspect and maybe change the `font-size` in multiple code blocks. The names of the code blocks that are relevant are:

- friends_chat_text
- friends_chat_text_self
- friends_chat_event
- friends_chat_bright_event
- friends_chat_url
- friends_chat_name_ingame
- friends_chat_self
- friends_chat_name
- friends_chat_accountid
- friends_chat_securitylink

You'll have to restart Steam to see the changes.

Be aware that changing these lines is changing the core Steam files, so they'll probably be overwritten when Steam updates. To make these changes stick (and be easier to remove), you might want to look into [how to make a Steam skin](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2510293), and keep your changes in that. (The downside of creating a Steam skin is then you face maintaining it if an update breaks it.)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! While your answer seems correct, it is not regarded as good practice to just link to another site. If you can, please provide a short summary of the solutioin on the other site, in case it goes offline or is unreachable in the future.

Comment: @MBraedley Fixed!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie +1

Comment: I feel like @SevenSidedDie should get some of the up-votes for the amazing edits he did.

Comment: `ChatRoomDlgFriend.res` file also controls the new Emoticon button, which can be removed by editing it. See this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124336/can-i-remove-emoticon-button-from-steam-friends-chat

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the font size in the chat input by changing font sizes in the files `ChatRoomDlg.res` and `ChatRoomDlgFriend.res` found under `Steam\friends`.

Search `font-size=` with ctrl+f and change the first occurrence in `ChatRoomDlg.res` and the first two in `ChatRoomDlgFriend.res` to the desired font size.

Answer (score 2):

As of now it is possible to prevent steam from replacing the `steam.styles` file by setting its `read only` property to true.

The font size of input box is controlled by another file: `Steam\Friends\ChatRoomDlgFriend.res`

Open it in any text editor and in section `styles`, subsection `Textentryfocus_chat` you will find the line `font-size=16`. Edit the number as you like.

But you should know that this file will be replaced on steam startup even if the `read only` property is set to true. So to keep the preferred font size, you will have to create a custom skin for Steam, but don't worry, it's very easy:

- Create a folder with a name that will be the name of your custom skin in `Steam\skins`
- Create a path `Steam\skins\<Your custom skin name>\resource\styles` and copy your edited `steam.styles` file there.
- Create a path `Steam\skins\<Your custom skin name>\friends` and copy your edited `ChatRoomDlgFriend.res` there too.
- Now restart Steam, go to `Settings > Interface`, select the skin you just created and restart Steam.