# Can I remove emoticon button from Steam friends chat?

Tags: steam

I'd like to remove the ugly smiley face button from my friend chat interface that I have no intention to use, and which is eating some of the input box space. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the File Steam/Friends/ChatRoomDlgFriend.res:

```
CEmoticonButton
{
    bgcolor="ChatDarkBG"
    image="graphics/icon_emoticon"
    padding-left=4

    render
    {
        // lines around
        0="fill(  x1 - 1, y0 + 1, x1, y1 - 1, LightBorder1 )"
        1="fill( x0, y0, x1 - 2, y0 + 1, DarkBorder1 )"
        2="fill( x0, y1 - 1, x1 - 1, y1, LightBorder1 )"

        // single pixel fills in the corners
        3="fill( x1 - 2, y0 + 1, x1 - 1, y0 + 2, MediumPxCnr )"
        4="fill( x1 - 2, y1 - 2, x1 - 1, y1 - 1, ButtonBorderDisabled )"
    }
}

CEmoticonButton:hover
{
    image="graphics/icon_emoticon_hover"
}

CEmoticonButton:selected
{
    image="graphics/icon_emoticon_hover"
}

EmoticonMenuItemStyle
{
    font-size=20
    padding-right=4
}
```

And a bit further down:

```
place { control="EmoticonButton" region=bottom height=38 align=right }
```

If you remove those, it should be gone. The problem is, that need to adjust the rest of the file for the removed lines. So it is really not a simple task of removing them. I had some success by testing it real quick, but I also got some weird glitches on the chat window.

Also, when Steam updates, it will be back, so it is better get into skin creation and make a skin that does not contain it.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file is still being replaced despite the read-only flag. I tried to lock it by opening in Excel, but the steam updater will just go in circles.

Comment: As I said, you need to create a skin

Comment: I'd *strongly* recommend making a custom skin for that purpose. Meddling with core files is *never* a good idea - and Steam tries to undo it for good reason.

Comment: My version of the file is a bit different, and so it took some time to remove the button from around the inputbox, but now it's floating behind the other person's userpic :\ Also, I was able to finally change the inputbox font size to 14 points! This is a really helpful answer!